# Design Filter with Arbitrary Magnitude and Phase Response in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response

Does anyone know of a way to design a filter with arbitrary magnitude and phase response in Matlab?

Comment: also, if your filter is causal, you can't do whatever magnitude and phase you want.  you might have to toss is some constant delay or linear-phase term in the phase, just to get a causal impulse response.  if it's causal, then $\Re\left\{H[k]\right\}$ and $\Im\left\{H[k]\right\}$ are a Hilbert transform pair.

Comment: What do you actually mean by arbitrary magnitude and phase response, do you mean that you can specify the filter in the frequency domain as a function, or only specify a finite number of points?

Answer (score 3):

for FIR, the simplest way is to inverse FFT you two-sided complex frequency response:

$$ h[n] = \operatorname{iFFT} \left\{ H[k] \right\} $$

(use a [Kaiser window](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/kaiser.html) to window the FIR to a length that is acceptable to implement.)

i presume you have access to [firpm( )](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/firpm.html) and/or [firls( )](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/firls.html).

so first divide your complex frequency response into real and imaginary parts:

$$ H_r[k] = |H[k]| \cos\left(\arg\{H[k]\} \right) $$
$$ H_i[k] = |H[k]| \sin\left(\arg\{H[k]\} \right) $$

send both $H_r[k]$ and $H_i[k]$ to the Parks-McClellan or Least Squares optimal FIR designer, but set `ftype` to `'hilbert'` for $H_i[k]$.

sum the two resulting real-valued FIRs to get your result.

lastly, if you want to design an IIR to an arbitrary magnitude and phase spec, then that's a much bigger problem and consideration.  maybe use Prony to design to your impulse response $h[n]$ or use Matt's dissertation that i first learned of now, or use [Greg Berchin's FDLS](http://apollo.ee.columbia.edu/spm/external/tipsandtricks/files/TandT_Jan2007.zip).  i dunno.  no quick solution for you there.

Comment: I'm trying to find more information on the method that devides the response in  real and imaginary parts and designs filters for them separately. It sounds promising for my application but I wonder what this technique is called and why it works.

Comment: I wonder the same things. It doesn't work for me at all.

Comment: What did you do?

Answer (score 2):

There's a PhD thesis with exactly this phrase in its title (including Matlab programs):

[Algorithms for the Constrained Design of Digital Filters with Arbitrary Magnitude and Phase Responses](http://mattsdsp.blogspot.nl/p/phd-thesis.html)

Comment: at first i thought it was in Deutsche (it's not, thankfully for me) but the next obstacle is reading it without reading it online. do you have it in .pdf, Matt?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: If you follow the link in the answer you'll see the abstract, but above it there's a download link for the pdf version.

Comment: I know I'm a bit slow: Matt, I didn't know you were one of Prof. Mecklenbräuker's students! Cool! :-)

Comment: @PeterK.: I was indeed. You know him? (Maybe this is not the place to discuss such things, but anyway ...)

Comment: Agreed, not the place!  I didn't know him, but I've read his work with Hlawatsch. I was just surprised to see the name.

Comment: @PeterK.: Yes, Franz Hlawatsch was a colleague of mine. As you know he has quite some name in time-frequency analysis, but he's been doing more work in digital communications in the past years.